# Sourceforge update latest version download

Tags: version-control, sourceforge

I just uploaded a new version of my application. And it's version 4.2.2. The old one is 4.2.1. On the summary page, the green download button is still pointing to the old version. How can I set the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Sign in to SourceForge and then:

- select the "Files" tab
- navigate to the file containing your new version
- click the icon that has a letter "i" in a black circle (next to the dustbin (trash can) icon) that appears at the far right end of the line containing newly released file's link
- a box of info about the file drops down: at the bottom right are several check boxes with associated operating system logos. Tick (check) all that apply to your release.
- click "Save"

Wait a while then go to the summary page and the file name should have changed to the one you want. You may to wait a few minutes before the change has any effect.

When you make another release do the same again for the new file. There's no need to clear your selections for the older files - SF does this for you.